# Adding 1 day to selected date in datepicker

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-ui

I'm trying to disable previous dates in End Datepicker.For Example if Selected date is 10-06-2021,the End date must be 11-06-2021. I need to disable all dates before 11-06 in End datepicker.
Please help me to resolve this.

```
<input type="date" name="datepickers" id="create-smeeting-startdate" />
<input type="date" name="datepickers" id="create-smeeting-enddate" />

var date = new Date(meetingStratdate);
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
$('#create-smeeting-enddate')[0].valueAsDate = date;
$("#create-smeeting-enddate").attr("option", "minDate", date);
$('#create-smeeting-enddate').change();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something along these lines:

```js
$("#create-smeeting-startdate").datepicker({
    // options
}).on("change", function() {
    $("#create-smeeting-enddate").val("").datepicker("option", "minDate", $(this).datepicker("getDate"));
});
$("#create-smeeting-enddate").datepicker({
    // options
});
```

Basically you handle the `change` event on first datepicker to set the `minDate` of second datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set "minDate" property to the datepicker.

In your case:

```
  $("#create-smeeting-startdate").datepicker({
    minDate: 1
  });
```

Comment: Hi Marian, Thanks for the effort, but I am getting the below error,                               
    Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous>

Comment: Try with a newer JQuery version

Answer (score 0):

**I think this is a perfect solution for your problem**

```js
var meetingStartDateInput = document.querySelector('#create-smeeting-startdate');
var meetingEndDateInput = document.querySelector('#create-smeeting-enddate');

meetingStartDateInput.addEventListener('change', function(){
    if(this.value != '') setEndDate(this.value);
});

    
function setEndDate(meetingDate){
    let date = new Date(meetingDate);
    // adding 1 day to meeting date
    date = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1));

    // This function add 0 before number if number is less than 10
    // * This function is important if you want to show date on html date picker
    function formatNum(num) {
        if(num < 10) return `0${num}`
        return num;
    }

    // change date format to "year-month-day" format to set on date picker value
    let newFormatedDate = `${date.getFullYear()}-${formatNum(date.getMonth()+1)}-${formatNum(date.getDate())}`;

    meetingEndDateInput.value = newFormatedDate;
    meetingEndDateInput.setAttribute('min', newFormatedDate);
}
```

```html
<div>Meeting date</div>
<input type="date" name="datepickers" id="create-smeeting-startdate" />
<div>Meeting End date </div>
<input type="date" name="datepickers" id="create-smeeting-enddate" />
```

Comment: Hi Narasing... Thanks for the effort... But I need to trigger the end date from another input (input type = "number") not from startdate.

Comment: Most welcome abhishek. from the number input we can select only day  or month or year. my suggest is use input type is "text" or "date".

Comment: Are you want to select just date from the number input and use month and year of now.